# Java how can I execute/run specific file by his path

Tags: java

I want to execute/run this file using Java.
The path is "/usr/local/studio.sh"

I tried:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] cmd = {"cd /usr/local","./studio.sh"};
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);


    } catch (IOException  e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}  }
```

but it doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Re-read what you wrote: `cd /usr/local/studio.sh`

Comment: Looks like you are trying to execute 2 commands. Use the full path, or use a ProcessBuilder and set its directory if you wish to have control over the root directory of the Process

Comment: In the cmd array, your first element is the command and all other elements are arguments to pass. This is actually running:
`$ cd /usr/local/studio.sh ./studio.sh`

Comment: @CJxD I try : String[] cmd = {"$ cd /usr/local/studio.sh ./studio.sh"};
still not run!

Comment: Sorry, you must have misunderstood. That's what it's actually doing, what you want to write most likely `String[] cmd = {"/usr/local/studio.sh"};`. You might also want to add `p.waitFor()` so the try block isn't completed until the system call returns. If you do want to `cd` first, change it to `cd /usr/local && ./studio.sh`. And make sure `studio.sh` is executable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ProcessBuilder` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and set the working directory using `directory(...)` instead of `cd` command.

In the end something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/bash","/usr/local/studio.sh")
pb.directory(...);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
IOUtils.copy(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work fine for me :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    String[] cmd = {"/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        p.waitFor();
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Runtime` API has a method to indicate the directory where you want to execute the method:

```
File folder = new File("/home/user/folder");
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, folder);
```

The `null` in this case indicates: "no environment" defined.

[Runtime API JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-)